# How do I pivot values from rows into column names in Postgres?

Tags: sql, postgresql, crosstab

I have a query in Postgres. It's working well and returns exactly the rows I'm looking for.

Here's the query:

```sql
select distinct on (status) id, status, timestamp
from my_table
where id = 1
order by status, timestamp
limit 500
```

This is what it returns:

| id | status | timestamp |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | started | 2022-01-15 05:12:36 |
| 1 | paused | 2022-04-14 09:12:50 |
| 1 | killed | 2022-04-27 13:12:48 |

**How can I pivot this table to return this exactly:**

| id | started | paused | killed |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2022-01-15 05:12:36 | 2022-04-14 09:12:50 | 2022-04-27 13:12:48 |

Comment: [Crosstab questions](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpostgresql%5D+and+%28%5Bpivot%5D+or+%5Bcrosstab%5D%29)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the extension [tablefunc](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/tablefunc.html), but it looks like a simple aggregate using a filter already works:

```
SELECT  id
    ,   MIN(timestamp) FILTER (WHERE status = 'started') AS started
    ,   MIN(timestamp) FILTER (WHERE status = 'paused') AS paused
    ,   MIN(timestamp) FILTER (WHERE status = 'killed') AS killed
FROM    my_table
WHERE   id = 1
GROUP BY id;
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Definitely easier to read than a `tablefunc` IMO.